# How to loop on field names of a class

Tags: c#, class, loops, field

I have got a class which contains more then 150 fields. i need the name of fields (not value) in an array.

because its very hard and not a good approach to write 150 fields name (which can be incremented or decremented in count according to requirement change) manually in code.

i need help to get loop through names for field or get list of field names in a array so that i can loop over it and use it in code.
i am using visual studio 2008

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

for all public + nonpublic instance fields:

```
var fields = typeof(YourType).GetFields(
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var names = Array.ConvertAll(fields, field => field.Name);
```

or in VS2005 (comments):

```
FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(YourType).GetFields(
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
string[] names = Array.ConvertAll<FieldInfo, string>(fields,
    delegate(FieldInfo field) { return field.Name; });
```

Comment: hi marc. its really good solution. can you please tell me that. is it same for visual studio 2005 or there will be other syntex?

Comment: actaully i have got a same application of previous version in vs2005

Comment: There's a small difference. You can't user ConvertAll in vs 2005, so you should use foreach instead. And also use concrete type instead of var.

Comment: @Rajesh, @StuffHappens You *should* be able to use ConvertAll, but the syntax will be more verbose - will update

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
var t = typeof(YourTypeHere);
List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>(t.GetFields().Select(x => x.Name));
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
    public static string[] GetFieldNames(Type t)
    {
        FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        return fieldInfos.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me perfectly ExampleClass is class You need list all fields

```
public void GetClassFields(Type t)
{
    List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>(t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(x => x.Name));
    foreach (string name in fieldNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }       
}
//Usage
GetClassFields(typeof(ExampleClass));
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me

```
var t = typeof(YOURTYPE);

var allfieldNames = new List<string>(t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Select(x => x.Name));
```

// t for Type